# How to prevent automatically rounding the decimal part of the number in .NET 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, rounding, asp.net-core-6.0

After I converted the version from .NET Core 3.1 to 6.0, I figured out that all `decimal(10, 5)` type columns were automatically rounding the decimal part of the number and saved it in the database with the round format. Which in the previous version of .NET Core was working correctly.
For example, I have a column like `asset = 85.456`, in the new version it is stored in the database with as a `85.46` value.

the upgrading version of the packages:
EFCore version 2.13.4 => 6.13.18
EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer version 2.2.6 => 6.0
and I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: What database? You only mention ASP.NET Core - which is the **web framework** -  but you mention nothing about the database being used, and how you're interacting with it. ...

Comment: You're right. I complete my question.

Comment: Added `sql-server`, and removed `asp.net-core-3.1` (its no longer that, because you converted)

Comment: Are you sure it's rounding in the database? Or rounding in the front end? I think the default edit & display format for a decimal is 2 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be sure about your model builder like this in context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.FieldName).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 5)");
});
```

If it is not for that, probably this field value type is not `decimal(10,5)` in your database.

Comment: yes, it works. Actually, in .Net Core version 3.1, I didn't use modelBuilder and it was working correctly. So, in .Net 6.0 I have to define all the properties with decimal type in modelBuilder?

Comment: It worked as a charm for me too

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Entity Framework. You need to set precision to let EF knows how to store decimal values in DB.

In your context, you can define the precision of the property as the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityName>().Property(x => x.DecimalPropertyName).HasPrecision(10, 5);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

You can also define this precision on the property using data annotation in Class or Model definition like the following:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(10, 5)")]
public decimal PropertyName{ get; set; }
```

[Ref about specifying decimal precision in EF.](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2017/03/29/entity-framework-tip-specifying-decimal-precision/)

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core 5, you can use a [precision attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#precision-and-scale) to define the column without needing to specify the raw database type.

```cs
[Precision(14, 2)]
public decimal Score { get; set; }
```

But if your actual problem is razor `<input` generation, then you could implement your own `IDisplayMetadataProvider` to use the same precision attribute to define the `.DisplayMetadata.DisplayFormatString` & `.DisplayMetadata.EditFormatString` for your view model.